# Dynamic Select input from MySQL grouping by each 5 years in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

sorry for disturbing you. I'm relatively new in PHP and need your help.

I have a database with thousand of records like these:

```
ID  |Year |Status|Action
001 |2016 |1     |Buy property
001 |2019 |1     |Build the house
001 |2021 |1     |Remodel
001 |2022 |1     |Rent new espace
001 |2027 |1     |Adapt new espace
```

I want to create a dynamic select input to use as a filter by years range like this:

```
<input type="select" id="selectFilterByYears">
    <option value="2016-2021">2016-2021</option>
    <option value="2012-2027">2022-2027</option>
</select>
```

That's the query I'm using to get the rows from database:

```
SELECT SUP_Numero ID, MPU_Ano `Year`, MPU_Programada `Status`,  TAC_Nome `Action` 
FROM view_mpacompanhamentogeral 
GROUP BY TAC_Nome
ORDER BY TAC_Nome
```

Can anyone help me to loop the rows and create the options I need in PHP?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Claudionir Queiroz

Comment: Your query is not correct, the columns in the select statement should be part of the group by or be part of any aggregation function like, SUM(), MAX()....

Comment: Hello Erges, the column is MPU_Ano, it is in the query. But if it is not the appropriated way, any sample will help a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using an old `MySQL` version because  in the newer version of `MySQL` and with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` enabled it will produce an error. For more details check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: `<input type="select"` is not correct - simply `<select id='selectFilterByYears'>`

Comment: I corrected the query. The only thing I need is to bring all records from a certain SUP_Numero (ID) with all years available to range them in the select option after.

Comment: The expected result shown ( ignoring incorrect `<input type='select'...` ) has a range `2012-2027` yet the db query does not have such a year. What criteria are you hoping to apply to the range of years?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 2022-2027 (5 years after the first year, that is 2016). I just need to group them like this  2016-2021, 2022-2027, 2028-2033 etc. Each 5 years.

Comment: you want group result by 5 years.. but why do you need a select? With a new selection of the select, make a new Ajax request and get the range you need.

Comment: I'm just creating a select field with the 5 years range that I'll use to filter the page after. I cannot set the select values in hard code, it should be dynamically, that's why I'm getting the available years in the database. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those facing the same issue. I solved my problem using this:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM table_or_view WHERE id = 'xyz' ORDER BY Year";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($res){
        $count = 1;
        $optAnos = "";                        
        while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            if ($count == 1) {
                $anoInicial = $reg["Year "];                
            }
            if ($count == 5) {
                $anoFinal = $reg["Year "];                
                $optAnos .= '<option value="'."$anoInicial-$anoFinal".'">'."$anoInicial-$anoFinal".'</option>';
                $count = 0;
                $anoInicial = $anoFinal + 1;
            }
            $anoFinal = $reg["Year"]; 
            $count ++;
        }
        $optAnos .= '<option selected value="'."$anoInicial-$anoFinal".'">'."$anoInicial-$anoFinal".'</option>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [between](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

first

```
explode('-', $yearsValue) //you get array with 2 year like ['2016', '2021']
```

and learn about between. I dont know what you use for query (PDO?)

**UPDATE**

I think you can get your param from `$_POST` or `$_GET` and put on `$yearsValue`

```
$years = explode('-', $yearsValue);
$qql = "SELECT SUP_Numero ID, MPU_Ano `Year`, MPU_Programada `Status`,  TAC_Nome `Action`  
FROM view_mpacompanhamentogeral 
WHERE SUP_Numero = $nsup AND 
WHERE MPU_Ano BETWEEN $years[0] AND $years[1];";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: I'm using mysqli_query and storing the result in variable $res. Like this: 
```$qql = "SELECT SUP_Numero ID, MPU_Ano `Year`, MPU_Programada `Status`,  TAC_Nome `Action` 
FROM view_mpacompanhamentogeral WHERE SUP_Numero = $nsup;" $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);```

Comment: update my answer

Comment: The query is not my doubt. I want to know how to get its result and create the select option grouping the returned years for each 5 years, like this: 
```<select id="selectFilterByYears">
 <option value="2016-2021">2016-2021</option>
 <option value="2016-2021">2022-2027</option>
 <option value="2028-2033">2028-2038</option>
</select>```

Comment: oh, now i understant.. maybe its easy do on `php` with `foreach`?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to use a while looping, but it is getting just the first and the last years like this: 2016-2023. It should be 2016-2021 and 2022-2023, do you understand?